# How to ensure that a foreign key may only appear a limited number of times in a table

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys

I'm trying to create some simple tables. I have one table with a list of members and another that links to the list of members via the foreign key memberNo. Can I constrain the second table to only allow an individual foreign key to appear three times, for example?

```
CREATE TABLE members(memberNo varchar(6) NOT NULL,
    fname varchar(10),
    lname varchar(10),
    PRIMARY KEY (memberNo));

CREATE TABLE activities(actNo varchar(6) NOT NULL,
    type varchar(30),
    memberNo varchar(6) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(actNo),
    FOREIGN KEY(memberNo) REFERENCES Members(memberNo),
    %CHECK(count(memberNo) < 6));
```

This is probably very simple, but I can't find a solution, so I'm probably asking the question incorrectly. I know that I don't want memberNo to be UNIQUE in the activities table, but to be allowed to occur only a limited number of times.

Comment: Which [DBMS product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no really easy way to do this in MySQL.  Here are two methods using triggers.

One method is for an `insert` trigger to count the number of rows in `activities` for a given member, and not allow updates that exceed the threshold.

A second method is to modify `members` to have a column with the number of activities -- typically requiring triggers on `insert`, `delete`, and possibly `update` in `activities`.  This value can then be used in the `insert` trigger on activities to check the value.

Two other methods are possible.  If all your data modifications are wrapped in stored procedures, then you can implement these in the stored procedures rather than in the database.  When designing systems, I often take this approach, but you have to be very careful that all modifications are controlled.

Finally, if you only want to allow two or three activities, you can have a separate column in members referring to each one.  I'm not thrilled with this approach but it does meet the need for small numbers of activities per member.